# MongoDB C# Driver to Retrieve 5000 documents Iteratively through Cursor using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, performance, mongodb, resultset

I am developing an asp.net Web App that is supposed to serve thousands of JPEG images to users. My dedicated server contains JPEG files and hosts a MongoDB to store JPEG metadata.

```
Sample object in a collection named **JPEG_123** (this collection has 1 million such documents and each document has _id indexed)
{ 
    "_id" : "20121210185015000", //YYYYMMDDhhmmsslll 
    "Url" : "http:...", 
    "CameraId" : 123 
}
```

I am using Web Methods to query MongoDB. I query collection **JPEG_123** for Utc field with Regular Expression (e.g. "^2012121018*/) to get documents for a single hour. It returns around 5000 records pointed by MongoCursor and on MongoShell it shows only 3-4 milli seconds time to retrieve this data.

**Q.** How can i get these documents iteratively from MongoDB the best and speedy way in ASP.NET through MongoCursor ? With optimum use of LIMIT, BATCHSIZE and NEXT like attributes of MongoCursor.

I am trying to do some thing like this:

- Execute above Find Query on MongoDB from ASP.NET
- Fetch only first 500 documents over the network initially and keep rest 4500 in RAM
- Fetch rest 4500 documents in that MongoCursor in 9 subsequent iterations (each time get 500)
- OR any other possibility to speed up this process of sending this data over the network

**My concerns**

1. When i query MongnoDB from ASP.NET, does it really mean that MongoDB loads all 5000 records to RAM but does not return all 5000 records to ASP.NET ?
2. After issuing the above query, it instantly returns total number of records pointed by the MongoCursor. When i loop through all documents in MongoCursor it takes around 20-30 seconds. Does that mean, MongoDB returns data when its used in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using cursors with large set sizes runs very slow unless the collection is indexed VERY well.  You should note that, for the most part, Regex precludes the use of indexes and you should try to avoid using those if at all possible.

By default cursors return 101 documents or 1 MB of data per batch.  If you can determine the size of your average document by looking at your collection stats, you can leverage that to set the best limit.  There are also settings you can play with in the cursor object to help expand out these limits to some degree.

One of the things I might suggest, since writes are already slow compared to reads, is to pass those UTC strings in as date fields and let Mongo parse those for you.  That way you can both index the field and use normal date ranges comparisons in your queries.